# lighttpd start/stop/restart script doesn't work

Tags: linux, lighttpd

I want to restart lighttpd using */lighttpd restart command, but nothing happens, no message, error, just a new cli line waiting for command.

I've examined lighttpd file and lighttpd.conf and they seem to be ok..

What should I do more ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure the `lighttpd` binary is correctly installed and executable? If the file is not found, the init script will just exit without doing anything.

The binary file is (at least on Debian) supposed to be `/usr/sbin/lighttpd`.

Comment: Debian here too, file is in /etc/init.d/.

I have tried /etc/init.d/lighttpd restart, nothing :(

Comment: @Claudiu: Is there a file `/usr/sbin/lighttpd`? That's where the actual program is supposed to be that the init script tries to start. If it's not there try `apt-get install lighttpd`.

Comment: You are right, lighttpd wasn't installed. I've installed it and everything is ok. THanks

Comment: This can happen if you had the package installed before and then removed it again. apt by default doesn't remove the config files in case you made changes to them that you don't want to lose.

Comment: Yeah, but I still have problems, I can;t start it now .. :(
port 80 is free.
When I try to start it is just say "Starting web-server: lighttpd"
and new cli line appears

Comment: @Claudiu: There should be log files in /var/log/lighttpd that might contain useful error messages.

Comment: I have reinstalled lighttpd.